# Is this question appropriate for Freelance Stack exchange?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Is the following question about USPS 'Prepaid Postage' appropriate for Freelancing forum?  *What are the annual fees, costs and general requirements associated with USPS 'Prepaid Postage'? Also, can 'Prepaid Postage' be used for packages?*

I was just searching the Internet for how to send prepaid packages to potential sellers, but only pay for the tyvek envelopes that are actually sent. That's when I learned about 'Prepaid Postage'. So, then I searched for costs and fees associated with 'Prepaid Postage' but let's just say the USPS does not seem to make it simple to understand. I did run across a 60-page PDF and thought wow, this is hours to figure out; and it could be very helpful to the general public to have a boiled down answer to this question on one of the stack exchange sites (because the USPS is doing such a bad job at explaining imo) . And, so here I am asking if this question is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like it would be off topic, as it's not directly relating to Freelancing. Asking for what fees happen to be would also not be constructive, as fees can change anytime.

Given the above, I would most likely vote to close as Off Topic.

Comment: My thinking was that freelancers & small-business owners often do bulk mailings. And that 'Prepaid Postage'  is a tool that is often used by  freelancers & small-business owners for marketing, delivery, etc.